# How to right Pig Script if line contains more than one same delimiter?

Tags: apache-pig

Here I have a line in my "test.csv" file as follows:

1987654,file not uploaded,please try again,Johnson

I would like to get output as follows using Pig

**Task ID**
 1987654

**Message**

file not uploaded,please try again

**User**

Johnson

Comment: Is it the only line? what does the rest of the data look like?

Comment: No,all data like it, one line after another. I have given only one line here. 1st line: 1987654,file not uploaded,please try again,Johnson 2nd line: 1987655,file uploaded,please continue,Clara 3rd line ....onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all lines have the same format, the simple solution is to load it into 4 fields with comma as the delimiter and then use CONCAT to join the 2nd and 3rd field along with a comma.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:int,a2:chararray,a3:chararray,a4:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE a1,CONCAT(CONCAT(a2,','),a3),a4;
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Yes, this is useful one, what happens if some line having message without comma. Ex: 1987656,error,Alex. Because message can come in any form. And it is .csv file

Comment: @SwadeepMohanty It won't work.This works since you mentioned all lines have the same format.